# Force page to ignore Cache - ColdFusion

Tags: caching, coldfusion

**Question:** *is it possible to force the browsers to pull the page from the server and ignore the cached version using ColdFusion?* I am looking for a quick temporary fix. Can I use the Application.cfc file to add a function to the `onRequestStart()`

**Background of Issue:** Recently a cache has been added to my companies website and every evening it runs caching the pages (even if they are broken or incorrect)

**My Research:** If I go to my site using this url I am served a cached page... http://www.mywebsite.com/  BUT if I add a generic variable in the URL I am served the page from my server:  http://www.mywebsite.com/?test=123

**What I have done so far:** In the case of links I have a function that adds the date and time to my page links so if they are used the page they point to pulls the current page.

Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide to help get feedback on my question.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this.

```
<cfheader name="cache-control"  value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<cfheader name="pragma" value="no-cache">
<cfheader name="expires" value="#getHttpTimeString(now())#">
```

Comment: We actually made a custom tag with something similar because we use it so often.